# MatLab:Grouping non-zero values depending of values in another vector

Tags: matlab, vector, grouping

Lets say,we've the following two vectors:

```
data =   [1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 ];
x_axis = [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 5 5 ];
```

What i now want to have is to count all data values which are for example one in the x_axis ,then these values which are two etc. So the result should look like as following (which i then can represent as a histogram):

```
  result=[5 8 16 8 8];
  x_axis=[1 2  3 4 5];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the perfect application example for `accumarray`:

```
data =   [1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 ];
x_axis = [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 5 5 ];

result = accumarray(x_axis(:),data(:),[],@sum)
result =
 5
 8
16
 8
 8
```